# Entity Framework Core updating unchanged fields

Tags: entity-framework-core, audit.net

I'm not sure if this is a question about Entity Framework, or how the audit.net library works, but I was guessing it was with how I was performing updates with EF. My goal is to capture only actual changes to the record, but it's capturing everything as change, even if the old and new values are identical.

Basically to simplify it as much as possible, if I do

```
var existing = context.Appl.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
context.Appl.Update(existing);
context.SaveChanges();
```

(Changing nothing)

The Audit.Net change log says every single field was changed, and looks like

```
   "Changes": [
      {
        "ColumnName": "FOO",
        "OriginalValue": "",
        "NewValue": ""
      },
      ..... many more
```

Comment: It will be very easy in getting the state of the entity on every change. Just think you have an entity and you have modified it 100 times. and you just want the state of this entity at the particular time. Otherwise it will be complex to get this kind of information

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.  I don't want to capture if the OriginalValue and NewValue are identical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My goal is to capture only actual changes to the record

Then you should not use the `Update` method.

According to the `Update` method [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext):

> Begins tracking the given entity in the `Modified` state such that it will be updated in the database when `SaveChanges()` is called.
>
> **All properties of the entity will be marked as modified**. To mark only some properties as modified, use `Attach(Object)` to begin tracking the entity in the Unchanged state and then use the returned `EntityEntry` to mark the desired properties as modified.

The main usage case for `Update` method is to perform a so called *forced update* when working with [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities). Since your `existing` entity is retrieved from the context (or in other words, is tracked by the context), hence all you need is to set the new values. Change tracker will detect if there are actual property changes and will issue `UPDATE` command with only modified values (or no `UPDATE` command at all if all current values are equal to the original values).